# Link Oracle Apex to SQL Database

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using the latest version of Oracle Apex 20.1
Within the Apex UI I am trying to create a Database Link that points to a SQL Database.
The apex account I am using to do this is an admin account with all permissions.
however, I am getting an error message related to permissions.

does anyone have experience with this?
Is it possible to create a database link to a sql server?

Comment: What SQL are you executing, and what is the error message?  FYI, you might get better response at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: To illustrate the problem, attach a screenshot to the question so that we'd see what you (and where) did.

Answer (score 0):

Note that an "admin" account in APEX is not the same thing as a DBA account in the Oracle database. The permissions required to set up a database link will need to be assigned to the database schema that APEX is creating the link in. Depending on your APEX setup, that may or may not have anything to do with the APEX account you log into, or that your application is trying to use to store objects. Additional changes to the Oracle server network configuration will also be required, and the installation of Oracle Transparent Gateways. You will definitely need the assistance of your DBA to set this up.

See here for more info on gateways: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/heterogeneous-services-generic-connectivity